# how can i solve the issue of right overflowed by 382 pixels

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, pixel, pixel-density

Problem:

I have an overflow error when i use this widget (code below), How i solve the issue?

You can see the error in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTPwA.jpg)

```
Container(
  height: 150,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  ),
  child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            )
)...
```

[You can check the complete here.](https://pastebin.com/0YBmb7sj)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the widget with Flexible().
Read more here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> The child Container should have defined height, try giving it a given height,
> and the height must not be greater than the parent height.
>
> - Increase the height of the parent container and also give the child Container a height and width
> ```

.

```
    Container(
      height: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Container(
               height:'your height',
              width:'your width',
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                )
    )...
```

Answer (score 0):

your `Row` widget is too big for screen. you should change your layout or wrap you code in `FittedBox` wiget like this:

```
Container(
        height: 150,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[...],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```